# Create Reference of React Elemets and Use it like Variable

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, frontend

I am trying to make a simple component that has text and image side by side. I am trying to implement it in such a way that the text can appear on right side and image on the left side and vice versa based on the props passed to the component.
Something like this:

```
    const TextAndImage = (props)=>{

          let RightComponent;
          let LeftComponent; 

          if(props.align == "text on right and image on left"){

             RighComponent = <p>This is Text</p>                     
             LeftComponent = <img src="source/to/image"/>

          }else{

             RighComponent = <img src="source/to/image"/>
             LeftComponent = <p>This is Text</p>                     
                           
          }
          
          return(
              <Col>
                  <Row> <LeftComponent/> </Row>
                  <Row> <RightComponent/> </Row>
              </Col> 
          )  

   }
```

How can I make reference `RightComponent` and `leftComponent` references and use them in such a way. Here I have used `<p/>` and `<img/>` tags. There could be React elements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components should be functions, not a jsx element. So:

```
RighComponent = () => <p>This is Text</p> 
LeftComponent = () => <img src="source/to/image"/>
```

You could also easily solve this using css with `display: flex` and then `flex-direcion: row` vs `flex-direcion: row-reverse` when you need to invert the order

Comment: Thanks :) That makes sense.